# RMIC exception while wsejbdelpoy

Tags: websphere, ejb-2.x

Following is the stack trace i get while using wsejbdeploy with ant script. I have multiple ejb modules that is ran for RMIC. and while this process it suddenly breaks in different projects

```
 EJB Deploy configuration directory: d:\applic\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\configuration/
[wsejbdeploy] framework search path: d:\applic\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\plugins
[wsejbdeploy] build:RAD851-I20121103_1921
[wsejbdeploy] 
[wsejbdeploy]                                                                                [*Error] An unexpected exception was thrown.  Halting execution.
[wsejbdeploy] Could not set classpath for CR_forRMIC
[wsejbdeploy] >com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploymentException (Could not set classpath for CR_forRMIC)
[wsejbdeploy] >org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException (Could not save the project location for '.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders'.)
[wsejbdeploy] java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\WP\WP2\online\jar\tmp\CR._\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders\.location (Access is denied.)
[wsejbdeploy]   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:232)
[wsejbdeploy]   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:153)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyOutputStream.<init>(SafeChunkyOutputStream.java:43)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyOutputStream.<init>(SafeChunkyOutputStream.java:39)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.writePrivateDescription(LocalMetaArea.java:398)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.internalWrite(FileSystemResourceManager.java:525)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.writeDescription(Project.java:1334)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.writeDescription(Project.java:1315)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.createLink(Resource.java:678)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.createLink(Resource.java:629)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ExternalFoldersManager.createLinkFolder(ExternalFoldersManager.java:153)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ExternalFoldersManager.createLinkFolder(ExternalFoldersManager.java:145)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ExternalFolderChange.updateExternalFoldersIfNecessary(ExternalFolderChange.java:48)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ChangeClasspathOperation.classpathChanged(ChangeClasspathOperation.java:62)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SetClasspathOperation.executeOperation(SetClasspathOperation.java:74)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:793)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3093)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3055)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3108)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.setupManualJarProjectClasspath(BatchExtension.java:2649)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.setupJarProjectClasspath(BatchExtension.java:1180)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.runJarDeploy(BatchExtension.java:684)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension$RunDeploy.run(BatchExtension.java:358)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1957)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension$RunDeploy.execute(BatchExtension.java:321)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.run(BatchExtension.java:284)
[wsejbdeploy]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[wsejbdeploy]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
[wsejbdeploy]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[wsejbdeploy]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
[wsejbdeploy]   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
[wsejbdeploy]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[wsejbdeploy]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
[wsejbdeploy]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[wsejbdeploy]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BootLoaderLoader.run(BootLoaderLoader.java:494)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BatchDeploy.execute(BatchDeploy.java:114)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.execute(EJBDeploy.java:106)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.deploy(EJBDeploy.java:348)
[wsejbdeploy]   at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.main(EJBDeploy.java:309)
[wsejbdeploy] EJBDeploy level: @build@
     [echo] **** Error while generating - WorkerPortal RMIC:The following error occurred while executing this line:
     [echo] D:\BuildFiles\DFRBLDD01VW_02_engine\BuildScripts\Worker_Portal_build.xml:682: Error in during Compilation of WorkerPortal RMIC:The following error occurred while executing this line:
     [echo] D:\BuildFiles\DFRBLDD01VW_02_engine\BuildScripts\Worker_Portal_build.xml:676: Java returned: 1 ****
     [echo] ***Build Failed: Error in RMIC Compilation ***
```

Comment: This [article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21227479) may be useful.

Comment: what version of WebSphere and what java are your using?

Comment: The "Access is denied" certainly implies a permissions or locking problem on that file (particularly since you're on Windows, which locks files more aggressively than Unix platforms).  Are you running multiple EJBDeploy processes simultaneously?  If so, it could be that they'd colliding on access to that file.

Comment: We are using WAS 8.5.5 and Java 1.7.64 . We have added a retry mechanism when ever the particular module fails which seems to work. But still wondering why it would fail in the first place. All the modules go in sequential order, there is no parallel processing